# Laravel. Blade. Вывод картинок в цикле

Tags: laravel, blade

Мне нужно получить все картинки из папки (storage/app/images) в контроллере, выбрать из них только нужные, создав из них массив. Передать этот массив на страницу и вывести в цикле с помощью Blade в src.
Скажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего нужно включить доступ к storage, подробнее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view).
Дальше нужно перебрать все файлы и добавить каждый в массив.

```
$imagesPath = storage_path('app/images/'); // путь к папке с картинками
$files = []; // массив файлов

foreach (glob($imagesPath . "*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) { // ищет все картинки через glob
    $files[] = $filename;
}  

return view('welcome', compact('files'));
```

Теперь в blade можно вывести вот так:

```
@foreach ($files as $file)
    <img src="/storage/{{ $file }}">
@endforeach
```

[Подробнее о glob](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php)

GLOB_BRACE - Раскрывает {a,b,c} для совпадения с 'a', 'b' или 'c'.

Если нужно проверить файлы регулярным выражением, взять точно те которые Вам нужно, то можно после foreach добавить:

```
$filteredArr = preg_grep("/str/i", $array); // возвращает у которых имя содержит str
```

Надеюсь я Вам помог!

Comment: В `compact` следует передавать не массив, а строки же

Comment: С массивом точно будет работать, со строками погуглил узнал что это правда, значит лучше просто строки передавать. Видите как laravel удобно под параметры подстраивается, так во многих функциях)

Comment: Пути до картинки выводит. Я уже и по другому делал. Но картинку не отображает. Картинки в самой директории есть. Пути к ним пишет(D:\OpenServer\domains\site\storage\app\public\images\image-2.jpg)

Comment: А какой src вставляется в img, есть ошибка 404 для картинок?

Comment: <img class="img-responsive" src="D:\OpenServer\domains\site\storage\app\public\images\image-2.jpg" alt="image-description">

Comment: по самой ссылке переходит к картинке

Comment: Если вставите `file:///` как префикс то должно работать, но этот вариант не подходит если сайт будет на хостинге. Вам нужно указывать путь оносительно сервера, чтобы laravel обрабатывал запрос. То есть вот так: `/storage/app/public/images/image-2.jpg`

Comment: Или проблема в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4090736/5286034). Попробуйте получать файл с сервера.

Comment: Не работает. Значит придётся править только вариант для хостинга.
Спасибо за ещё один вариант исполнения по выбору файлов.

Comment: @denis_che `storage:link` выполняли? Ссылка создалась?

Comment: Да, это я выполнял.